# Display Graphics Drivers for Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, 20.04, intel-graphics

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 & Windows 10 as Dual Boot, I wanted to know that the Display Graphics Drivers in Windows are different, and in Ubuntu it is different, but the System remains the same.

I am asking because the Size of the Display is bigger compared to the Display Drivers are in Windows 10, I wanted to know that can I use that or a similar driver for Ubuntu 20.04?

please help me if anyone has an idea about this.

Sincerely,
Dhaval

Comment: In no way can you use Windows drivers in Ubuntu. What does this mean? *Size of the Display is bigger compared to the Display Drivers are in Windows 10

Comment: can I use any other Drivers in Ubuntu? because if you compare the Icons of Windows & Ubuntu, then Icons of Windows are smaller than Ubuntu

Comment: That has nothing to do with drivers. The size of the icon is controlled by the Desktop Environment.

Comment: No, it has to do with Display Graphics Drivers, as I've noticed this thing in Windows that's why I am asking you otherwise I don't have any intention to bother anyone on this Forum Community.

Comment: Good luck with this.

Comment: It sounds to me like you may be having a resolution problem. This could sometimes be resolved by installing graphics drivers, but according to your comments on the answer here, I don't think you need to install graphics drivers (because all the necessary graphics drivers for Intel devices are already in the Linux kernel, I believe). So, perhaps you can try to change the resolution, or other settings, to get the appearance you want. Otherwise, perhaps you can edit your question and add screenshots to explain what you want to change - it is not easy for me to understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

run `ubuntu-drivers devices` and you'll see hardware vendor and related drivers, for example:

```
$ ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001F82sv00001458sd00003FCBbc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : TU117 [GeForce GTX 1650]
driver   : nvidia-driver-418-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-450 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-460-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-450-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-460 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

choose a stable driver to install, in here, I'll choose `driver   : nvidia-driver-460 - distro non-free recommended`

because it is `recommended`

run `ubuntu-drivers install nvidia-driver-460` to install the driver.

if succeed, reboot the system.

Comment: means as you mentioned above that I can choose `driver: nvidia-driver-460 - distro non-free recommend` it will help me to reduce the icon size like it is in Windows after installing Display Graphics Driver?

Comment: no, it only help you and ensure you have the right driver installed.

Comment: all thing will blur or bigger if the driver is incorrect and has the wrong resolution configed.

Comment: I am looking to reduce the Icon size like we've in Windows after installing Display Graphics Drivers because due to it, every Icon, other Apps size are sort of bigger than compared to Windows.

Comment: currently `Intel® HD Graphics (ILK)` this Graphics Driver is installed in my Ubuntu 20.04 system

Comment: @DhavalVira If you're looking to change icon size, ask *how to change icon size*, not about drivers! It's totally unrelated!

Comment: it is related to Drivers, without confirming from my end, I am not spamming it is in Drivers, if I've seen this thing that's why I am asking and it is totally relevant.

Comment: it means I will not get help from the Forum, and Sorry if I was harsh, Thank Your for your help.